# Lagging Issue in Hindi Language in Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I have a lots of text in label and text in Hindi Language in Tableview.
Hindi text get via PHP web service. But so much lagging in tableview.
Not scrolling smoothly. Take so many hanging and lags.

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and text convert in readble format code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    GroupPost *post=(GroupPost*)[[arrMsg objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([post.postType isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cellIdentifier=@"GroupDetailCustomeCellTextOnly";
    }

    /////////Text Convert in URLDecode and get readble text....

    NSString *unicode=[[post.postContent URLDecode] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

     cell.lblPostContent.text =unicode;

     return cell;
}

//This Function Use For URLDecode....
- (NSString *)URLDecode {
    return [self URLDecodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *)URLDecodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                             (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
                                             CFSTR(""),
                                             CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Please guide me how to make scroll very smoothly and remove hanging and lagging issue from my Tableview.

Comment: before table view load. make an complete array from your webservice and use background queue for datasource !also update UI at main thread... may be it work smooth.

Comment: @Pushp Post some code..plz

Comment: Where are you creating your `UITableViewCell`? put that code snippet.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara in view didLoad==> [tblViewList registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GroupDetailCustomeCellTextOnly" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GroupDetailCustomeCellTextOnly"];

Comment: Its only registering cell. Where are you initialising your cell?

Comment: @DipenPanchasara  cell=(GroupDetailCustomeCell*)[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[GroupDetailCustomeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process
    NSMutableArray *unicodeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (i = 0; i < arrMsg.count ; i++)
    {
        GroupPost *post=(GroupPost*)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *unicode=[[post.postContent URLDecode] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        [unicodeArray addObject:unicode];
    }
});
```

Use unicode array as a datasource. try out let me know what happend. put this code at viewDidLoad

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tableView reload]
    });
```

put this code at viewDidAppear

Comment: error get in main thread block=>no visible @interface for 'UITableView'declares the selector reload

Comment: and where i set my value in label like,=> cell.lblPostContent.text =unicode;

Comment: and you change your value in cellforrowatindex path

Comment: like ==>cell.lblPostContent.text =[unicodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      ???